# font-weight not being applied in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Anyone know what would explain why font-weight is the only declaration not being applied in this scenario?

HTML

```
<div id="page_title">
    <h3>Page Title</h3>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#page_title {
  color: rgb(90, 190, 190); 
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

For some reason both the color and the family are being applied but not the weight. The div is inside the header tag with no other styles being applied to the header or h3 elements.

**EDIT**

It is worth mentioning the google font has been imported above the external stylesheet inside the HTML file like so:

```
<!-- Import Google Fonts -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

It is also worth mentioning that the font-weight can be applied if I target the h3 selector but not the id. So font-weight is working, just not if I use the id.

Comment: Please post the code you have to import the Roboto font from Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `font-weight` applied to the `h3` by the user agent style sheet is overriding the `font-weight` cascading from the container (your `#page-title`).

[image]

Try applying the `font-weight` directly to the `h3`.

BUT NOTE that the `h3` is already **bold**, and `font-weight: 700` is [an exact equivalent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight), so you would not see any difference anyway.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight):

[image]

Comment: Haha, I just edited my post saying it does work on the h3. Can you elaborate on what you mean by user agent overriding the font-weight ?

Comment: I've just added a screenshot from the Chrome Inspector. As you can see, the default `font-weight` rule (applied by the browser) is overriding your rule.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying in the Inspector. That is kind of a pain that the user agent is overriding. Applying the style directly to the h3 does work indeed. Is their a way to override the user agent and still apply to the ID ?

Comment: The `h3` is being targeted directly by the browser style sheet. If you want to override that setting, you need to target the `h3` directly, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Michael :)

Answer (score 0):

**sometimes it's not working so you just import google fonts.**

```
<link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono|Roboto+Slab|Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel = "stylesheet" />
```

**Verify my answer if it's work for you.**

Comment: The font being imported was assumed. But to clarify, I edited the original post showing just how it was imported. So unfortunately this is not the issue. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#page_title {
  color: rgb(90, 190, 190); 
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#page_title h3{
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div id="page_title">
  <h3>Page Title</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: font-weight: 700 is equal to bold

Comment: That did not work. I think the user agent override is the problem as Michael has said.